# Can I lock down custom taxonomies on a parent term level, but not a child term?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

I've created a taxonomy called "topics" which has 4 top level terms:

1. science
2. environment
3. technology
4. cant remember the last one

and each of those terms will have child terms. I want to be able to lock down the top level terms but not the child term.

Basically editors should be able to create as many terms as they want for each of those top level terms.. But those top level terms cant be deleted or modified.

Is that possible?

Comment: If the answer has been helpful consider accepting it - if you need more information read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and [Why is voting important?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote).

Answer (score 2):

This not a complete and ready-made answer, but the below should get you started.

First thing to note is, deleting and modifying are different functionalities, so different functions and hooks are relevant to it. Namely we are talking about [`wp_delete_term()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_term) - [source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L2027) and [`wp_update_term()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_term) - [source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L2915) - regarding the functions.

So lets take a look at [`wp_delete_term()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_term), you have to at least consider two hooks: [edit_term_taxonomies](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L2076) and [delete_term_taxonomy](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L2119). They are both relevant because of the bulk action and because of the handling of hierarchical taxonomies.

Below some exemplary code how to approach this. I've tried to explain the most important things inside the code. The rest you have to read up on yourself.

First the [edit_term_taxonomies](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L2076) hook:

```
add_action(
    'edit_term_taxonomies',
    'wpse160191_top_level_lock_down_edit_term_taxonomies',
    10,
    1
);
function wpse160191_top_level_lock_down_edit_term_taxonomies(
    $edit_tt_ids
) {
    $screen_obj = get_current_screen();
    $base = $screen_obj->base;
    $taxonomy = $screen_obj->taxonomy;

    if(
        // these are the conditions we are checking against
        // is this a tag edit page
        $base == 'edit-tags'
        // we want this only for a specific taxonomy
        && $taxonomy == 'category'
        // not super and/or admin
        && ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' )
        // a least an editor
        && current_user_can( 'manage_categories' )
    ) {

        // these are the terms up for deletion
        $terms_queue_for_deletion = $_POST['delete_tags'];
        $term_parents_ids = array();
        // we need information if or not one of the terms is a top level one
        foreach ( $terms_queue_for_deletion as $term_id ) {
            $term_obj = get_term_by( 'id', $term_id, 'category' );
            $term_parent = $term_obj->parent;
            $term_parents_ids[] = $term_parent;
        }

        if( empty( $edit_tt_ids ) ) {
            return;
        }

        if( ! empty( $edit_tt_ids ) ) {
            if ( in_array( 0, $term_parents_ids ) ) {
                $msg = new WP_Error(
                'parent_terms_are_forever',
                __('Sorry, you are not allowed to delete top level terms.')
                );
                wp_die( $msg );
            } else {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Second the [delete_term_taxonomy](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L2119) hook:

```
add_action(
    'delete_term_taxonomy',
    'wpse160191_top_level_lock_down_delete_term_taxonomy',
    10,
    1
);
function wpse160191_top_level_lock_down_delete_term_taxonomy(
    $tt_id
) {

    $screen_obj = get_current_screen();
    $base = $screen_obj->base;
    $taxonomy = $screen_obj->taxonomy;

    if (
        // these are the conditions we are checking against
        // is this a tag edit page
        $base == 'edit-tags'
        // we want this only for a specific taxonomy
        && $taxonomy == 'category'
        // not super and/or admin
        && ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' )
        // a least an editor
        && current_user_can( 'manage_categories' )
    ) {
        $term_obj = get_term_by( 'term_taxonomy_id', $tt_id, 'category' );
        $parent_id = $term_obj->parent;
        if (
            // this applies only to top level terms
            $parent_id == 0
        ) {
            $msg = new WP_Error(
                'parent_terms_are_forever',
                __('s:Sorry, you are not allowed to delete top level terms.')
            );
            wp_die( $msg );
        }
    }
}
```

As mentioned above, it gets a bit more complicated, mainly because of the AJAX actions. If you are thinking about doing this with the well known and simple check:

```
if ( defined('DOING_AJAX') && DOING_AJAX ) {
    // code
}
```

I can tell you right now, that I'm pretty certain it won't be sufficient enough. Mostly because you won't be able to do all the checks you need. If you are fine with just disabling or, to be exact, removing the link to the AJAX action, you can do it somewhat like this:

```
add_action(
    'admin_head' ,
    'wpse160191_remove_ajax_delete_link'
);
function wpse160191_remove_ajax_delete_link() {
    $screen_obj = get_current_screen();
    $base = $screen_obj->base;
    $taxonomy = $screen_obj->taxonomy;

    if(
        // lets just remove the link on that one page and not everywhere
        $base == 'edit-tags'
        && $taxonomy == 'category'
    ) {
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                var element = 'span.delete';
                $(element).each(function(){
                    $(element).css('opacity', '0');
                    $(element).css('pointer-events', 'none');
                    $(element).remove();
                });
            });
        </script>
    <?php
    }
}
```

Of course you shouldn't do it inline and so on, but you can optimize yourself. This of course is not very satisfying, because we just removed the functionality.

One way I imagine to deal with the AJAX action would be to make use of [`debug_backtrace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php). This would offer a way to determine and handle the AJAX action correctly. It could be implemented into the above shown code. A caveat of course is that `debug_backtrace()` is performance-wise expensive and in a larger scale surely not recommendable.
Another way would be to implement your own AJAX action as replacement for [`wp_ajax_delete_tag()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/ajax-actions.php#L530), but to do so you have to additionally either have to extend the [`WP_Terms_List_Table`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-terms-list-table.php#L10) or use some hooks in there to achieve this. Not exactly sure at the moment, so you have to inspect that further yourself.

The procedure for [`wp_update_term()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_term) and disallowing updating/modifying is analogous to the above shown. With the same considerations concerning the AJAX part, especially because of the inline quick edit possibility.

---

*At first I totally misread the question and gave this as an answer.

Keeping it because it might be useful to others.*

What you can do is hooking into the [`pre_insert_term`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L2410) to do the checks needed.

**Code:**

```
add_action( 'pre_insert_term', 'wpse160191_restrict_top_level_term_creation', 10, 2 );
function wpse160191_restrict_top_level_term_creation( $term, $taxonomy ) {
    if( 
        // these are the conditions we are checking against
        // we want this only for a specific taxonomy
        $taxonomy == 'topics'
        // a value of 0 or -1 does indicate the top level
        && $_POST[ 'parent' ] <= '0'
        // not super and/or admin
        && ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' )
        // a least an editor
        && current_user_can( 'manage_categories' )
    ) {
        // the user is an editor and not allowed to add parent terms
        // so return a friendly message so the user at least knows 
        return new WP_Error(
            'parent_terms_not_allowed_for_editors',
            __('Sorry, you are not allowed to add parent terms.')
        );
    } else {
        // a super and/or admin, s|he is allowed to do what s|he wants
        return $term;
    }
}
```

The [`pre_insert_term`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L2410) hook is part of the [`wp_insert_term()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term) function.

*Some Notes:*

- The `parent` value of the [`$args` is `0`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L2389), when no parent is selected. But we have no access to those inside the action, the form does return the value of `-1` for `$_POST[ 'parent' ]` if »None« is selected. So `<= '0'` should work in any case.
- We are not passing the user role to the `current_user_can()` function, because that is just [**wrong**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can#Notes) - although you see it a lot, it still is bad. Instead [capabilities](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) are used to determine, which kind of user we are dealing with.